# JavaScript function not working for 2nd HTML file because it is triggered by button in first HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

The Function "addItemToCart" is not working for my 2nd HTML file maybe because #place and .bag-btn are used in 1st HTML file and that calls the function on click.

Can someone help please? Thank you.

```
$(function () {
  $("#place").on("click", ".bag-btn", addItemToCart);
});

function addItemToCart() {
  console.log("Button Pressed");
  var btn = $(this);
  var parentDiv = btn.closest(".img-container");
  let id = parentDiv.attr("data-id");
  console.log(id);
  $.get("products.json", function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      var res = response[i];
      if (res._id == id) {
        //second page work starts here
        $("#tabelBody").append(
          `<tr><td>res.title</td><td>res.price</td><td>1</td><td>res.price</td></tr>`
        );
        //above line will add the clicked product in the cart Table
        var totalPrice = totalPrice + res.price;
        $("#totalPrice").append("Total Price = " + totalPrice);
      }
    }
  });
}
```